# Windows 7: Unmapped Drive Letter Shows Up

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7: Unmapped Drive Letter Shows Up](https://superuser.com/questions/419991/windows-7-unmapped-drive-letter-shows-up)

As can be seen in the screenshots below, a weird drive letter shows up under "Computer" which however is not mapped in the Disk Manager. I guess it is some kind of service that creates this drive. How can I find out, which service or program is responsible for it? How can I remove it?

Pictures:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7678110/pic1.jpg

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7678110/pic2.jpg

Comment: Looks like a very large usb drive, are you linked to a network drive, or have a usb drive

Comment: Does anything show if you right-click and then click on shrink-don't shrink it but what happens

Comment: Sorry about this:>  Does anything show in System Information -> Components -> storage -> Drives