# Windows 7: Unmapped Drive Letter Shows Up

Tags: windows-7

As can be seen in the screenshots below, a weird drive letter shows up under "Computer" which however is not mapped in the Disk Manager. I guess it is some kind of service that creates this drive. How can I find out, which service or program is responsible for it? How can I remove it?

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll probably get more useful eyes on this at SuperUser.

Comment: Drive label is Hulk.... Dis you set it?

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to Office Click-and-Run. [This Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982434) has more information:

> Why do I have a "Q:" drive when I use Office Starter To-Go?
>
> Office Starter To-Go uses the Office Click-to-Run technology that must use a virtual application drive. This virtual application drive is why you have the Q: drive.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have Office 2007, so I'm afraid it is not office...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's created using `SUBST`?

Usage:

```
C:\Users\graeme>subst /?
Associates a path with a drive letter.

SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
SUBST drive1: /D

  drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
  [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
                 a virtual drive.
  /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.

Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.
```

Example, make the local drive G: refer to C:\Users\Graeme\Desktop:

```
C:\Users\graeme>subst g: c:\users\graeme\desktop
```

Show existing:

```
C:\Users\graeme>subst
G:\: => C:\users\graeme\Desktop
```

Unlike mapped drives, virtual drives created using `SUBST` do not persist between sessions, so it is typically used in a logon script if persistence is needed.

Comment: I tried subst, but no mappings appear. It has to be some service I guess, I just don't know which one. Is there any way to get the creator of a virtual drive?

Comment: Both SUBST'd drives and mapped drives are only visible in the session they're created in, so if a service created it, it's unlikely you would see it in your session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the CD/DVD ROM, it is likely to be a virtual drive mounted from an ISO file.  We had exactly the same problem and it turned out to be UltraISO and just went to Tools.Mount Virtual Drive and disabled it

Comment: It's not a CD-ROM. I disabled all virtual CD drives in PowerISO. The Q-Drive is still there

Answer (score 0):

Do you have APP-V (-aka SoftGrid) installed?  Microsoft Application Virtualization mounts its ".SFT" file to drive Q: to run applications.  The file it mounts would be located here: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Application Virtualization Client\SoftGrid Client"

As others have said, typically it won't show up in Disk Management if its a mounted container file like an ISO, SFT, BIN, etc.

Comment: Don't have it installed.. I'm still looking for a way to find the responsible program for any mapped drive letter...